# resource-proxy class… C++ best practices

Tags: c++, value-class

I have a common problem to write a C++ wrapper for a C library… my main storage a C-Struct pointers who represent always a C++ class containing just **ONE** data filed.

```
class MyClassC {
  struct MyStructS * hdl
  ...
}
```

creating all the constructors, static and method function is NO problem… my design problem is right now… should I use a *value* class design or a *pointer* class design.

### *value* class always return the object and **NOT** the pointer:

a *value* class has a **ONE** to **MANY** relationship between *MyStructS* and *MyClassC*

```
MyClassC myMethod () {
  ...
  return MyClassC(struct MyStructS *...);
}
```

Destructor of a *value* class never **free** the **struct MyStructS pointer** and is mostly empty

Destructor of a *value* is an *static* or *method* mainly called *destry* or *delete*

```
MyClassC::delete() {
   DestroyMyPointer(&hdl)
}
...
MyClassC obj = {...};
...
obj.delete();
...
```

a *value* class is the argument on methods a *value* as well:

```
some_proc_or_method (MyClassC arg1, MyClassC arg2, …) {
   ...
}
```

and there is an other question:

> how do i create default arguments for a *value* class argument?

```
some_proc_or_method (MyClassC arg1, MyClassC arg2 = MyClassC {...} ???? ) {
   ...
}
```

### *pointer* class always return the pointer of the object:

a *pointer* class has a **ONE** to **ONE** relationship between *MyStructS* and *MyClassC*

```
MyClassC* myMethod () {
  ...
  return this or getThisFrom(myStructS_pointer)
}
```

Destructor of a *pointer* class always **free** the **struct MyStructS pointer**

```
~MqClassC () {
   DestroyMyPointer(&hdl)
 }

...
MyClassC* obj = new MyClassC(...);
...
delete obj;
...
```

Comment: Both of your approaches seem broken to me

Comment: There is no one-size-fits-all, so it depends on what `MyMethod` is supposed to do. Now it is totally abstract. It is also pretty common for C++ functions to return references instead of values or pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for option 3: a thin wrapper that gets the ownership correct first. The C code is already useful in C++. The only actual benefit to gain in wrapping it is to get the ownership semantics *right*. Both of your approaches try to place the burden of keeping track of ownership onto the user of your API. That's not a useful wrapper, it just adds a superfluous layer of indirection. Your clients will still need to mind the internals of the C API to be effective.

What I suggest instead is that you return a smart pointer with clear ownership semantics. Write a bunch of inline free functions that accept the smart pointer and forward to the C API. The net result is that you have almost the same API (less of a learning curve), with C++ ownership semantics. That's a gain, and the result would be less cumbersome.

```
#include <memory>
#include <CLibAPI.h>

namespace CPPWrapC {
  namespace detail {
    struct DestroyMyPointer {
      void operator()(MyStructS *hdl) {
        ::DestroyMyPointer(&hdl);
      }
    };
  }

  using Handle = std::unique_ptr<MyStructS, detail::DestroyMyPointer>; 


  Handle myMethod() {
    MyStructS *ret = /* init it */;
    return Handle{ret};
  }

  inline void some_proc_or_method(Handle const& hdl) {
    c_lib_some_proc_or_method(hdl.get());
  }
}
```

So now you have a simple wrapper that supports handles with single ownership semantics. Exactly what you wanted, I think. And using it is almost exactly like using the original wrapped API, so clients can leverage whatever they know about the C library to work.

And this can serve as a stepping stone. Now you have a C++ type you can include as a member to wrap things further.

Comment: handle seems something like a *value* class.

Comment: @AndreasOtto - It's not a value type. Since AFAIK a requirement for those is to be copiable. As for your own, somewhat uncommon, use of the term, I deliberately avoided it